# Why does Directory.Exists("%HOMEPATH%") == true with .Net Core Console but not Windows Desktop Console?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I have two console executables each using the same library. One exe is written using .Net Core and the other using Windows Desktop Console. In the library, written using .Net Standard, I have common code including a method to validate a command line argument that might have a directory location as a string. In the project properties on both I have a Debug `'Start option > Command line argument' "%HOMEPATH%\Documents\'`. When the .Net Core program uses the .Net Standard library it finds the folder but when the Windows Desktop program uses the same library the directory is not found! Why?

Project Debug startup options command line arguments value:
`"%HOMEPATH%\Documents"`

Code from the .Net Standard library:

```
public static void ValidateWorkingDirectory(ref string workingDirectory)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
    {
        Log.Warning("The working directory argument is not valid! Arg: {0}. Defaulting to current running directory: {1}", workingDirectory, Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    }
}
```

Interestingly, it is similar if I put `%HOMEPATH%\Documents` into the project properties / Debug / Working directory. On the .Net Core project that is fine but on the Windows Desktop Console it shows the dialog "The working directory does not exist."

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is the not so subtle distinction between Unix and Windows.  The desktop version never intended to target Unix but .NETCore certainly did (MacOS and the many Linux flavors).  A Unix programmer never expects to have to expand an environment variable himself, the shell always does it for him.  You should be able to use Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables() to make the difference disappear.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28890

Answer (score 0):

Method Directory.Exists in standard .Net Framework expects absolute or relative path to directory, allies like '%HOMEPATH%' doesn't work. In this case this method tries to find folder called '%HOMEPATH%'. This behavior might be different in .Net Core.

To make it work you need to use something like that:

```
var envVariable = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH");
var isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(envVariable);
```

Please keep in mind that value for GetEnvironmentVariable doesn't contains '%'.

For more info please have a look at this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/sidebar/system-environment-getenvironmentvariable